# keras trying to shape arrays to suit input

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, keras

I have a model with inputs like this

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

I've tried to shape the data in a number of different arrays (32x32=256 floats from grayscale images)

```
X = []

for fn in os.listdir('input'):
    a = misc.imread('input/'+fn) / 256.0
    a = a.flatten()
    X.append(a)
#X=np.array(X)
#X=np.reshape(X,256,50)
#X=np.array(X) #.flatten()
```

How do I properly order the data for input ?

Comment: 32*32=1024
16*16=512

Comment: for some reason 32x32!=256 Doh! 1024 seems to work much better - one of those days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reshape your input as the following (replace `num_of_rows`):

```
input = X.reshape((num_of_rows, 32 * 32))
```

And then using the `input_shape` to specify the shape to keras:

```
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(32 * 32,)))
```

You can even go ahead and transform the values to a 0-1 scale:

```
input = input.astype('float32') / 255
```

Comment: i tried reshaping but I get error like: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 51200 into shape (50,256)

Comment: for some reason 32x32!=256 Doh! 1024 seems to work much better - one of those days...

Comment: For some reason, haha.